# Init method coverage while running unit tests

Tags: ios, unit-testing, code-coverage

I have a init method in my class which has a corresponding unit test in the test file and also executes successfully, but when I check the coverage of the unit test using Cover Story tool it doesn't take init method into account. Any idea why does that happen? Is there any way I can make init method count into the coverage?

Below is my init method and unit test for it:

***Init Method of class:***

```
- (id)init
{
    NSException *exception = [NSException exceptionWithName:@"Incorrect initializer."
                                                     reason:@"Use initWithDelegate as the initializer."
                                                   userInfo:nil];
    @throw exception;
}
```

***Unit Test for init method:***

```
- (void)testInit
{
    ClassA *temp = [ClassA alloc];

    STAssertThrows(temp = [temp init], @"init should have thrown an exception.");
}
```